# How to open Text File with .OpenText in VBA that starts with first column like "ID" without getting SYLK error

Tags: vba, excel

I've come across a nasty little bug in Excel VBA's `.OpenText` method..  It errors on opening any text or CSV file when the first two letters are upper-case "ID".  Here is the article from MS so you know I'm not crazy: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626

So, I'm trying to figure out a workaround that does NOT involve copying the entire file just to re-name the first header.  I am working with some large text files and this would be an unsatisfactory last resort.

I've tried `On Error Resume Next` before the `.OpenText` call but that didn't work..  Has anybody come across this and found a simple solution I'm missing?  Is there a way to just crack open the first line and find/replace inside of a text file?  Or extra parameters to `.OpenText` I could use?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the text? Can you import it any other way (Import Text Wizard, ODBC or something?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this for you. Just call it passing the filepath prior to attempting to open it. I deliberately wrote this with late binding, so no references are required. it will add an apostrophe to the beginning of the file, if the file starts with "ID".

```
Sub FixIDProblem(filePath As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim text As Object
    Dim contents as String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(filePath) Then
        'Open the file for reading
        Set text = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
        'Load the text contents to variable
        contents = text.ReadAll
        'Check for the forbidden text at the beginning
        If Left(contents, 2) = "ID" Then
            text.Close
            'Overwrite textfile with it's contents plus an apostraphe
            Set text = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 2)
            text.Write "'" & contents
        End If
        text.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "File does not exist"
    End If
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome!  So this is essentially just reading into memory instead of copying to another physical file...  Tried it once on a pretty big file (20MB) and was definitely fast enough for my use.  Thanks!

Comment: It reads it into memory, and then overwrites it if it needs to do so. Otherwise, it just gets closed and nothing is done to the file. I did it this way because I figured you wouldn't want a temp file created... also this is better.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the alerts off:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="startwithID.tab"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this instead :

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myfile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Local:=True
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myfile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The first OpenText fails, but the second one works.

The FixIDProblem is a good idea but fails on big files (~ 40MB)